# Process task parallel to one another instead of serially in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, subprocess

Task1: I have a ~120Gb set of the document from which one program is continuously extracting "ids".

Task2: Once all "ids" are extracted I have to process each of the "ids" and extract some data which links to each "id".

I have written a python script which performs this serially, i.e Task 2 on completion of Task 1. I was wondering if there is a way in which as an when each "ids" is found in Task1, it sends it to Task2 immediately for processing while itself resuming to look for the next "ids". Basically, make both tasks work parallelly to save time.

Comment: sounds like a problem for a database script?

Comment: So... Multiprocessing? Did you google anything about python parallelism?

Comment: The DB would be dynamically be updated, would be hard to track which ids are processed. Will have to keep flags to update db about processed or not processed along with new ids being added.

Comment: I couldn't find anything supporting multiprocessing. Most documents talk about threads which act serially

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing reminds me of [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Some other recommended libraries:

- [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)
- [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)